# In centos - No module named lazy_object_proxy while executing prospector library for python

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, centos, virtualenv

After installing prospector by using `pip install prospector`, I execute this command.

```
prospector --version
```

I got this error

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/ec2-user/ingestion/acadenv/bin/prospector", line 7, in <module>
>       from prospector.run import main
>     File "/home/ec2-user/ingestion/acadenv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prospector/run.py", line 8, in <module>
>       from prospector import blender, postfilter, tools
>     File "/home/ec2-user/ingestion/acadenv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prospector/tools/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
>       from prospector.tools.pylint import PylintTool
>     File "/home/ec2-user/ingestion/acadenv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prospector/tools/pylint/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
>       from pylint.config import find_pylintrc
>     File "/home/ec2-user/ingestion/acadenv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pylint/config.py", line 48, in <module>
>       from pylint import utils
>     File "/home/ec2-user/ingestion/acadenv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pylint/utils.py", line 39, in <module>
>       from astroid import nodes, Module
>     File "/home/ec2-user/ingestion/acadenv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astroid/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
>       from astroid.nodes import *
>     File "/home/ec2-user/ingestion/acadenv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astroid/nodes.py", line 39, in <module>
>       from astroid.node_classes import (
>     File "/home/ec2-user/ingestion/acadenv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astroid/node_classes.py", line 24, in <module>
>       import lazy_object_proxy
>   ImportError: No module named lazy_object_proxy`

Moreover I have executed `pip install lazy_object_proxy` but this does not solve the problem also.

Comment: I've had the same problem on Debian. Uninstalling and installing python-lazy-object-proxy again worked well.